# PS4 connection with Controller

Tags: ps4, controllers

I have a relatively new PS4 controller (one or two months old).

One day, I took it over to my mate's house to play some FIFA, when I can home later that day I went to plug in my controller and connect like normal. The light went orange to show it had been connected and so I pressed the PlayStation button, but all it does is flash with the white light? This is also happening with other controllers I try to connect... already synced ones connect no problem. I thought it may have been a random thing but it connects to other people's PlayStations, just not mine.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the controller? Great guide here https://evilcontrollers.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/220270708-My-PS4-Controller-Won-t-Sync-with-the-Console

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1. Turn PS4 Off
2. Reset PS4 Controller (Small hole on back of controller, will need something small to press it)
3. Plug controller into PS4
4. Turn PS4 back on
5. Press PS button

I've had luck with this method in the past.